# Conditional Combo Box Multiple Column

Tags: excel, vba

I have a problem where I want to make Combobox2's result dependent on Combobox1's result.

For example:

```
a     1     x
a     2     y
b     2     z
b     3     x
c     3     z
d     4     z
```

Here's the code:

```
Private Sub Combobox1_Change()
Dim wslk As Worksheet
Set wslk = Worksheets("Sheet1")

Dim i As Integer
Combobox2.Clear

For i = 2 To wslk.Range("B" & Application.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
If wslk.Range("B" & i).Value = Combobox1.Value Then
Combobox2.AddItem wslk.Range("A" & i).Value

'The problem starts here
Combobox2.Column(1, i - 2) = wslk.Range("C" & i).Value
Combobox2.ColumnCount = 2
End If
Next i


End Sub
```

So far it has been able to populate Combobox2 with result from Combobox1.

For instance, if in Combobox1 I choose "a", Combobox2 will show "1" & "2".

However, the moment I choose anything in Combobox1 other than "a" it will crash saying:

```
Combobox2.Column(1, i - 2) <Could not get the Column property. Invalid property...
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you want to add `Combobox2` column two value `x and y` for a?

Comment: But, example you show us at the beginning of your question, does not start form column A:A? If yes, looking for 'a' in column B:B will not find a match... Does it start from B:B column?

Comment: `Column(1, i - 2)` is wrong. It will happen to match your first row in the sheet... I will post an answer clarifying the issue...

Comment: @Harun24HR Yes! That was the intention!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the next code, please:

```
Private Sub Combobox1_Change()
Dim wslk As Worksheet, cb2 As MSForms.ComboBox

Set wslk =  Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set cb2 = Me.ComboBox2
Dim i As Long
cb2.Clear

 For i = 2 To wslk.Range("B" & Application.Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
    If wslk.Range("B" & i).Value = ComboBox1.Value Then
        With cb2
            .ColumnCount = 2
            .AddItem wslk.Range("A" & i).Value
            'The problem starts here (not anymore...)
            cb2.Column(1, cb2.ListCount - 1) = wslk.Range("C" & i).Value
        End With
    End If
 Next i
End Sub
```

Your code should add the item after the last existing one (`cb2.ListCount - 1`)...

Comment: Wow this works like a charm! Thank you so much for the help.

Would you mind teaching me why I should change the code to:
`cb2.ListCount - 1`
Instead of previous 
`i - 2` Because it worked for "a" but not the rest.

Comment: @Zainedevontay: I tried suggesting that, in a way, in the last sentence... So, the new item will be add after the last existing one. In first case it worked in your way (by chance) only due tu the fact that first element was zero and the second one was 1 (the i values). But trying the same approach for, let us say "b", or "c" combo value, it will not work. Since you cleared the combo, its first element must be added in the zero list index. According to iteration, it will be 4 - 2 = 2. And the combo cannot accept a list index bigger then its `ListCount -1`. Minus ` because first index is zero.

Comment: @Zainedevontay: And if you like the answer, voting it up would not kill anybody able to do that... :)

Comment: I see. I think I still a lot of stuff to learn! Thanks for the explanation. Oh and yeah I was planning to vote it up but didn't have enough reputation. However I just again enough to do it. Thanks again!